# Disable Woocommerce main shop page, but not the product category archive pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to find the best practice to disable the main "`/shop`" page in Woocommerce, **without** disabling the category product pages. There doesn't seem to be an answer for this anywhere... Does anyone know how to do this?

I did find a bunch of semi-similar posts which hide every shop (category) page or simply replace the content in archive-product.php to create a 404...
So to help clarify: The goal is to keep the category product pages like "`/shop/clothing`", but only disable the main "`/shop`" page without causing any SEO disadvantages. (I assume setting the shop page to **no index** would affect the category pages as well?)

Thank you so much in advance for solving this.

Comment: What precise SEO disadvantages do you believe you are facing? What is the harm of letting the shop page exist, but just not linking to it? Otherwise, the best answer may vary substantially depending on your theme and general structure - how your users are expected to get to the "category product pages" in the absence of a top level shop page.

Comment: Thank you for your time @CK MacLeod. - For some categories I have created a custom page instead. And to avoid double content pages, I did not create a category for them within Woocommerce. So, the shop page does not show all the actual categories. Therefor, I would like to hide it. Visitors can reach each category through the menu or custom pages. - Now... If I let the shop page exist, won't it be shown in search results? If I set it to 'no index', I assume category pages within Woocommerce also get the no index status... right?

Comment: I frankly don't know anything about inheritance of "no index" status, and i still don't see much harm in having a basic shop page "out there," but I think that the best practice-y way to achieve what you want, and the way least likely to encumber you in the future, would probably be a customized shop page template - which could entail a redirect if that's your preference - or a simple redirect (achievable in various ways) from the shop page to any other page of your choice. Without viewing your site in detail, I can't say more.

Comment: That brings me back to my original question :) How can I edit the archive-product.php to only redirect the "`/shop`" page, without redirecting category pages like "`/shop/clothing`" - Leaving the shop page out there in this case would have people land on an incomplete overview if search engines show it. - But thank you for your time @CK MacLeod , I appreciate that.

Comment: Well - if you've already tried it, please show your code or settings and link to or detail the results!